# Select Min And Max Value from one table with same id in one row

Tags: sql

I have table like this:

```
| ID |Size|
|----|----|
| 20 | 30 |
| 20 | 31 |
| 20 | 32 |
| 20 | 33 |
| 21 | 16 |
| 21 | 17 |
| 21 | 18 |
```

How can I select that to show result like this:

```
| ID |     Min   |  Max |
|----|-----------|----- |
| 20 |      30   |   32 |
| 21 |      16   |   18 |
```

Answer (score 3):

use `min/max` aggregation with `group by`

```
select id, min(size), max(size)
from tablename
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative Way:

```
select distinct id,
min(size) over(PARTITION  by id)as minsize, 
max(size) over (PARTITION  by id) as maxsize 
from test order by id;
```